# Adding "allowsEditing" to custom UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I integrated a so called `OLFacebookImagePicker` into my application.
[From Here.](https://github.com/OceanLabs/FacebookImagePicker-iOS)
For my app I need images to be cropped to squares like the `allowsEditing`
of the native `UIImagePickerController` does.

My Question is:
Is it possible to integrate this feature in a custom PickerController?

I've got the idea to **MAYBE** get the images from the `OLFacebookImagePicker`
into the app and manipulate them afterwards. But I want to give the users the chance to customize their pictures by themselves.